# How to change the vertex layout

Tags: graphs-and-networks

*(Using V9 on Ubuntu)*

Consider the following code, to create a graph.

```
f[x_] := Mod[x^11, 100]; 
NV = 22;
V = Table[i, {i, 1, NV}]
FV = Table[f[V[[i]]], {i, 1, NV}]
EV = Table[DirectedEdge[V[[i]], FV[[i]]], {i, 1, NV}]
```

The output is nice.

[image]

From the Help we get a way to change the vertex layout:

[image]

So I defined a function for circular layout and tried again:

```
circle[n_] := Table[{Cos[2 Pi/n u], Sin[2 Pi/n u]}, {u, 1, n}]
Graph[EV, VertexCoordinates -> circle[NV]]
```

but the output was only a list of points:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vn = VertexCount[Graph[EV]]
(* 36 *)
Graph[EV, VertexCoordinates -> circle[vn]]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why is necessary to compute the vertex again? `vn` is not equal to `NV`!

Comment: @Sigur, a graph with `EdgeList` `EV` has `nv` (36) vertices, not `NV` (22); and the setting for the `VertexCoordinates` option should be a list of length 36 (a coordinate for each vertex). (BTW, you might want to change "vertex shape" in your post to "vertex layout" or to "vertex coordinates".)